# Compare List from 'embedded' table with main column

Tags: powerquery

(see screenshot)  i have my main table and in a column I have an embedded table.  I need to compare Date column in embedded table with a condition AND test with against column in main table...  I thought I could use List.Transform to bring a list of the Dates (which I can) but if I try to do a List.Transform on this function (that returned the list) i get an error

We cannot convert a value of type Function to type Type.
Details:
Value=[Function]
Type=[Type]

`= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom", each  List.Transform(  List.Transform( [MD_call_Data][Date], each _ )),  each  Date.Month(_) = Date.Month(#date(2023,2,1) and _ < [Min. Blood_Collection_Date] ))`

I also tried columns as List and it errors
List.Transform([MD_call_Data][Date],
each  Date.Month(_) = Date.Month(#date(2023,2,1) and _ < [Min. Blood_Collection_Date])))

pl see screenshot for column Headers.  how can i bring in the list and compare against a column and another condition?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEmhs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are shooting for?

- you need Number.From() wrapped around dates to compare them
- you need to use the let xxx in yyyy format to pull in a field before
  this List.Transform

  ```
  #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom", each let test=[Min. Blood_Collection_Date] in List.Transform([MD_call_Data][Date], each Date.Month(_)=2 and Number.From(_)<=Number.From(test)))
  ```